# Обратиться к статической переменной класса

Tags: php, массивы, ооп

Нужно при создании объекта добавить его в массив, но при дампе говорит что массив пуст, что я делаю не так?

```php
class apple
{
    private $arr_cou = 0;
    public $date;
    public $status;
    public $Aple_persent;
    public static $apples = array();


    function __construct($obj)
    {
        $this->date         = 0;
        $this->status       = 0;
        $this->Aple_persent = 0;
        $apples[$arr_cou]   = $obj;
        $arr_cou++;
    }
}

$a = new apple($a);
```

Comment: а вот эти странные закорючечки, которые ты пишешь - `$this->` - они вообще для чего?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь добавить значение в массив, который находится вне функции? Если да, то, к сожалению, функция просто не знает о существовании этого массива вне функции и строка "$apples[$arr_cou] = $obj;" просто создаёт массив $apples в функции __construct, который никак не связан с массивом $apples вне класса

Comment: в конструкторе присвоить значения по умолчанию переменным

Comment: Unzerstorbar, разве конструктор не должен видеть публичные поля класса?

Comment: а где здесь в конструкторе *публичное поле класса*, я стесняюсь спросить?

Comment: `self::$apples[] = $this;`

Comment: Ипатьев, поле apples к примеру

Comment: каким местом эта свободно висящая в пространстве переменная относится к классу?

Comment: @Ипатьев а минус мне вы поставили? скажите хоть, что не так. Это ладно. Ну а тут: человек забыл или не знал, как обращаться к статическому полю. Но очевидно же, что он пытается сделать? Это какой-то новый метод обучения, надавить на спрашивающего?

Comment: Честно, я думал он понимает что делает, но просто в упор не видит опечатки. И я пытался навести его на эту мысль, чисто по аналогии, если к $status как-то по особому приходится обращаться, то наверное при обращении к $apple тоже надо что-то написать?

Comment: Все-таки, важна интонация =) Непонятно, с издевкой человек пишет или как-то иначе. Пардон, не так понял =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К статическому свойству нельзя обращаться просто через `$`, нужно использовать `self::`.

Вы можете класс в простейшем случае исправить так:

```
<?php

class apple{
    public $date;
    public $status;
    public $Aple_persent;
    public static $apples = array();

    function __construct() {
        $this->date=0;
        $this->status = 0;
        $this->Aple_persent = 0;
        self::$apples[] = $this;    // сохраняйте объект в массив, ключ указывать не обязательно
    }

    // добавить статическую публичную функцию, которая будет доставать количество объектов в `$apples`
    public static function count()
    {
        return count(self::$apples);
    }
}
$a = new apple();
$b = new apple();
$c = new apple();

var_dump(apple::count());   // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Обращаясь к статическому свойству класса вы должны указать ключевое слово `self`

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php

а чтобы обратиться к свойству объекта вы должны использовать экземпляр этого объекта.

иными словами это:

```php
$apples[$arr_cou] = $obj;
```

измените на это:

```php
self::$apples[$this->arr_cou] = $obj;
$this->arr_cou++;
```